# How to capture regex in vim and do the substittion

Tags: regex, vim

What will be regular expression for deleting all the text inside the "" quotation in vim?

I am getting problem is using capture block in this case.

```
INPUT:

<A HREF="www.sitenotvaialable.com" ADD_DATE="0.0">16</A>
<A HREF="http://www.cnet.com/"      ADD_DATE="0.0">17</A>
<A HREF="http://www.flickr.com/"   ADD_DATE="0.0">18</A>
<A HREF="http://www.white-fox.co"  ADD_DATE="0.0">19</A>

OUTPUT:
<A HREF="" ADD_DATE="0.0">16</A>
<A HREF="" ADD_DATE="0.0">17</A>
<A HREF="" ADD_DATE="0.0">18</A>
<A HREF="" ADD_DATE="0.0">19</A>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work for your example:

```
%s/"\zs[^"]*//
```

if you like, you can record macro to achieve that too (using less keystrokes):

(assume your cursor is at line 1)

```
qq0di"j@qq
```

than you type `@q` to replay the macro for all lines in your buffer.

note that the recursive macro is just for saving `999@q`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If would have been great if you explainthe \zs

Comment: @dearvivekkumar `:h \zs`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
:%s/HREF="[^"]*"/HREF=""/
```

By using `"[^"]*"` instead of just `".*"` you avoid matching all the way past the first closing quote to the later closing quote of the second attribute.